# Karate: Query Param values are getting encoded

Tags: bdd, karate, query-string

I am using **karate 0.6.1** version and facing issue with `get` request with queryparam.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify the response Data with account details when there are filter values are provided with wildcard

 Given params { <paramName>: <paramValue> }
 When method get
 Then status 200
 Examples:
   | paramName | paramValue |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   | Name       |  'Volvo%' |
   | Name       |  'test data'|
```

in the request url with queryparam becomes like `url?Name=Volvo%25`
And `url?Name=test+data`

which is not correct, how should i resolve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually not wrong,

Url encoding is required to differentiate between special characters in your data vs special characters that are reserved to construct the URL.

**Reserved Characters URL Encoding:**

```
:   Separate protocol (http) from address encoded as %3B
/   Separate domain and directories encoded as %2F
#   Separate anchors encoded as %23
?   Separate query string encoded as %3F
&   Separate query elements encoded as %24
@   Separate username and password from domain encoded as %40
%   Indicates an encoded character encoded as %25
+   Indicates a space encoded as %2B
<space> Not recommended in URLs encoded as %20 or +
```

so if you are going to pass any special characters as data via URL you need to **`% encode`** them to avoid conflicts.

In karate, if you want to avoid your URL getting encoded, don't construct your URL using **path, params, param** definitions.

Instead, build your entire URL as a string and pass it to `url`. like,

```
* url 'http://httpbin.org/get?Name=Stark'
```

> You might get an exception if you are trying to pass any special
>   characters in this.

so consider encoding the URL if you are going to pass any special characters.

Comment: Could facing similar issue in form field if I have special character,
* form field username = 'test@test.com'

It's changed to test%test.com

Comment: could you please give any example for passing @ in query param or form field