# Karate framework symbol encoding in url

Tags: karate

I have this:

```
Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my_exchange'

Scenario:
    Given path 'publish'
```

Problem here is that the url is being resolved as:

`http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges///my_exchange/publish`

instead of:

`http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my_exchange/publish`

Thanks

EDITED:

I will improve the question.

I uploaded a very simple project here: https://github.com/italktothewind/karate-encoding

It has a wiremock listening to `/bar/%2F/foo`

This feature is working:

```
Feature: Working example

    Scenario:
        Given url 'http://localhost:1081/bar/%2F/foo'
        When method get
        Then status 200
```

But this feature is not working (I put an @ignore flag in the project so it can be built successfully):

```
Feature: Non working example

Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:1081/bar/%2F'

Scenario:
    Given path 'foo'
    When get
    Then status 200
```

The difference between the two features is the use of `url` and `path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything/%2F/my_exchange'
* method get
```

And in the log:

```
1 > GET https://httpbin.org/anything/%2F/my_exchange
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/1.8.0_231)
```

EDIT: when you have un-conventional URL-s the general recommendation in Karate is to use only the `url` (don't use `path`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53638335/143475

Comment: I am having the issue using version 0.9.2 of karate-apache and karate-junit4

Comment: @italktothewind follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I definitely have an issue, I will submit an issue when I can build a minimal example, thanks!

Comment: I researched a bit more and the issue appears when you use url in the background and path in the scenario (like the example in the question) and not url directly in the scenario (like this answer)

Comment: @italktothewind I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I improved the question

Comment: @italktothewind got it, this edge case is a `won't fix` for me. if you have unconventional URL-s our guidance is to not use `path`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53638335/143475 - you are free to disagree and contribute a PR

Comment: I will accept this answer as it shows a workaround, but maybe it should be edited indicating that no path is used at all