# How to use param having two equals symbol in Karate?

Tags: parameters, karate

My API path looks like `https://google.com/search?sort_by=name&query=name=test`
How are we supposed to give the query param `query=name=test` in Karate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `param`:

```
* url 'https://google.com/search'
* param sort_by = 'name'
* param query = 'name=test'
```

The `=` sign will get URL encoded, so refer this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977660/143475