# Why karate dsl replace "space" for "+" in param

Tags: karate

i have this code:

```
Scenario: Get Token     
Given url 'https://localhost/api/accessToken'     
And param scope = 'collections payments'
```

Log:
1 > POST https://localhost/api/accessToken?scope=collections+payments

This Post faild for me.

Please, i need this:
https://localhost/api/accessToken?scope=collections%20payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is doing the right thing and your server probably has a bug.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634293/143475

But if you want to send it the way you are asking, put it as the URL itself, and don't use `param`:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything?foo=one%20two'
* method post
```

Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977660/143475

Comment: thanks Peter, but this example is API POST with Query Params, this works? cause im getting *http call failed*

Comment: @JesusOvalle I have nothing to add to my answer, as I said - maybe something is seriously wrong with your server. I suggest you work with someone who understands the server-side on your team, or someone who knows how to send the correct request to your server. karate supports get, post and everything, refer the docs. if still stuck - follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: A little late to the party, but did you try `And param scope = karate.urlEncode(collections payments)`