# Param between url in Karate Testing

Tags: javascript, java, testing, karate

I have situation like this:

```
* url address
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    * configure ssl = true
    * path 'compliance' + '/accept'
    * param id = 10101016
    * def req = {"decision": <decision>, "reasonId": <reasonId>, "comment": <comment>}

    Given request req
    When method PUT
    Then status 200
```

resault:
.../compliance/accept?id=10101016

And always my param go to end in url but I want this param between url like this:
.../compliance?=id10101016/accept

How can I do this ? I am trying everythink but not working :/

I am looking answer on the internet but everywhere param go to the end of url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me say that looks like a very badly designed API. Anyway you can do this:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything/compliance?=id10101016/accept'
* method get
```

And refer this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977660/143475

And if you are worried about dynamic data, that's not a problem:

```
* def id = '10101016'
* url `https://httpbin.org/anything/compliance?=id${id}/accept`
* method get
```

I would think this is the right way:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path 'compliance?=id10101016', 'accept'
* method get
```

And yes, the `?=` will get encoded, but that's how HTTP is supposed to work.