# Karate DSL query parameter does not accept empty spaces and converts them to encoded charactesr

Tags: api, karate

Parameter value does not accept special characters and throws syntax exception. Same URL works perfectly fine in postman

[image]

However in Karate there is concept of encoding and decoding which is tough to comprehend. Can you please provide example using the following scenario

```
Scenario: Searching owner name with family organisation name of characters greater than 141
Given path '/api/products/v1/ownerName/search'
And param familyOrgName = "MCLAREN VALE & DISTRICT SUB-BRANCH OF THE RETURNED SAILORS', SOLDIERS' AND AIRMEN'S IMPERIAL LEAGUE OF AUSTRALIA, SOUTH AUSTRALIAN BRANCH INC."
When method Get
Then status 200
```

[image]

karate version: 1.3.1

I tried to decode and encode the URL and refactored the code

```
  Scenario: Searching owner name with family organisation name of characters greater than 141
    * def encoded = 'MCLAREN+VALE+%26+DISTRICT+SUB-BRANCH+OF+THE+RETURNED+SAILORS%27%2C+SOLDIERS%27+AND+AIRMEN%27S+IMPERIAL+LEAGUE+OF+AUSTRALIA%2C+SOUTH+AUSTRALIAN+BRANCH+INC.'
    * def decoded = karate.urlDecode(encoded)
    Given url sailisUrlBase + '/api/products/v1/ownerName/search?familyOrgName=' + decoded
    When method Get
    Then status 200
```

[image: ReportFailed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have not set the `url` correctly. You can try this test and see it work. You can even see the server process the `param` correctly and echo it in the response:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* path '/api/products/v1/ownerName/search'
* param familyOrgName = "MCLAREN VALE & DISTRICT SUB-BRANCH OF THE RETURNED SAILORS', SOLDIERS' AND AIRMEN'S IMPERIAL LEAGUE OF AUSTRALIA, SOUTH AUSTRALIAN BRANCH INC."
* method get
* status 200
```

And don't worry about encoding, Karate will do it automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977660/143475

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas. it is working perfectly fine now.