# Can the sequence of param be maintained based on how it is feeded in the feature file sequence?

Tags: karate

I have a use case where for some reason the sequence of param do yield different http response and therefore because of that the test case is failing.

```
Given url 'http://myurl.com'
And path '/mypath'
And param _x = abc
And param f = xyz
Then print response
```

When the karate forms the entire url structure, it is shown as -
http://myurl.com/mypath?f=xyz&_x=abc
But I would like it to be the below-
http://myurl.com/mypath?_x=abc&f=xyz

The reason I want it to be latter only because then only i am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `url` keyword without using `param`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977660/143475

```
* url 'http://myurl.com/mypath?_x=' + abc + '&f=' + xyz
```

Thanks for reporting this! I've [made a change](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/commit/3f8477eed79856b09d403a97dab0f90b527131b0) so Karate respects the order in which you supply each `param` in the next version.

Comment: Thank you so much @Peter and I would love to see the next version soon. We have many api's that takes multiple query string and using the concatenation would be a nightmare to handle which is what I also did based on how you have suggested.

Comment: @USingh keep in mind that most people would consider this a high-priority bug in your server - and karate has probably "caught" this for you. this is the first time in 7 years that someone has requested this.