# param is not taking %2B

Tags: karate

In my Karate Script, I am giving param input = '%2B61293744000'. I have used %2B for encoding + as it is a phone number with country code. 
Now the URL that is formed is taking input as input=%252B61293744000 , which means that the % itself has been taken as %25
Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53638335/442595

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that in Karate if i directly give  param input = '+61293744000' this is working fine, and url is formed as %2B which is correct
So no need to encode it in parameter.